# How to delete a row from Database and DataGrideView in C# with clicking on the button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to write a program and it has an admin page . in the admin page's, there are two button A)Delete B)Edit 
as you know each button must do Delete and Edit
I have tried many codes for deleting section but it didn't work as I expect it. here is my code that I found on the web:

```
void Delete()
{
    string ID = "0";
    if (ID != "0") {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DB_Project;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand delcmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM TBL_UserName WHERE Row = @Row ", con);

        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open) 
        {
            con.Open();
            delcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Row", ID);
            delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Your information has deleted");
            Display();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a row ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work exactly? You get any exception or error message? Unexpected result? You need to be more specific about your problem.

Comment: You'll have a long wait for it to work with string ID = "0";
    if (ID != "0")...